# Countif with specific criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use countif to count a name but only want the count to go ahead if the cell next to it displays yes.

E.g.

```
George   Yes     Count for George would be 1<br>
Andy      No      Count for Andy is 0<br>
George    No       Count is still 1 for George<br>
Bob       Yes      Count for Bob is 1<br>
George    Yes       Count is now 2 for George
etc
```

My current code is `=IF(COUNTIF($E$3:E5,E5)=0,"",COUNTIF($E$3:E5,E5))`.
Which displays the count without taking into account Yes or No.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

Check this option using SUMPRODUCT and confirm if this is how you want it row by row. Or if you have a separate table or list of Unique Names elsewhere.

[image]

For this sample data the formula in H2 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:F2=F2)*($G$2:G2="Y"))
```

Drag it down up to the intended rows.

Comment: Thanks, one other question. Can I stop reset after 3?

Comment: It seems this answer has worked for you as per your above question. If so I suggest leave this QnA as it is now and ask a new question with your new requirement to reset after 3. You may give link to this question therein but provide all details in new question so that it can be answered separately.

Comment: @Bob, you didn't appreciate this answer (by clicking the checkmark near it) and still require the help with the other? Do you think that it is fair?